# Did not got email confirming payment and registration for release exam

Tags: certification, release-exam

I did my credit card transaction for my Maintenance exam. Amount was deducted from my credit card but I have not got any confirmation email also I am redirected to payment console again.

Do I have to make a new transaction? or Will this be settled down?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get an answer that you are happy with, you can open a case with SF and have them sort it out for you. --->[Open a SF case](http://certification.salesforce.com/open-a-case)